# How to Remove validation from left table data in django

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

[2nd Screenshot of API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3g85.png)[API Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Mj1.png)

I'm New in Django, i want to help regarding validations in screenshot there is company_name, location, title and user_location fields except user info with proper validation 
but i want to remove validations from  company_name, location, title and user_location fields how to do?

Please find the above api screenshot and

Please find the below scripts,

**views.py**

```
class UserRegistrationView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Register a new user.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )

    def get_serializer_class(self, user_type=None):
        if user_type == 'student':
            return StudentRegistrationSerializer
        return ProfessionalRegistrationSerializer

    def post(self, request, user_type=None, format=None):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class(user_type)
        serializer = serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'request': request})

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

            user = serializer.save(work_status=user_type)
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            data = BasicUserSerializer(user, context={'request': request}).data
            data.update({"token": token.key})
            return Response(data)
```

**serializes.py**

```
class ProfessionalRegistrationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=20, write_only=True)
    experiences = ExperienceSerializer(required=False)
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password',
        'experiences', 'headline')

    def validate_email(self, value):
        from validate_email_address import validate_email
        if User.all_objects.filter(email=value.lower()).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User with this email already exists.')
        # if not validate_email(value.lower(), check_mx=True):
        #     raise serializers.ValidationError('It looks like you may have entered an incorrect email address.')
        return value.lower()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        experiences = validated_data.pop('experiences')
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        email = validated_data.pop('email')
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=email.lower(),
            email=email.lower(),
            role_id=1)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        user_location = experiences.pop('user_location')
        if hasattr(user, 'location'):
            user.location.location = user_location
            user.save()
        else:
            UserLocation.objects.create(user=user, location=user_location)
            Experience.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

**Another serializes.py for Experiance**

```
class ExperienceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    user_location = LocationField()
    location = LocationField()

    class Meta:
        model = Experience
        fields = ('id', 'company_name', 'company', 'description', 'location',
        'title', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'is_current', 'user_location')
```

I want to Remove Validation from company_name, company, description, location, title, start_date, end_date, user_location

actually these fields are second page means after complete the first step users move on second step so second step fields are optional

```
class ExperienceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    user_location = LocationField()
    location = LocationField()

    class Meta:
        model = Experience
        fields = ('id', 'company_name', 'company', 'description', 'location',
            'title', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'is_current', 'user_location')

        def create(self, validated_data):

            return Experience.objects.create(field_a='value', field_b='value')
```

in the above class, what should be do to remove validation of

```
"error_msg": {
        "location": [
            "Expected a dictionary of items but got type \"str\"."
        ],
        "start_date": [
            "Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]."
        ],
        "end_date": [
            "Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]."
        ],
        "user_location": [
            "Expected a dictionary of items but got type \"str\"."
        ]
    }
```

**Experience Model**

```
class Experience(models.Model):

    """
    """

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='experiences')
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey('organisations.Organisation', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey('regions.Location', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, blank=True)
    is_current = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_associated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_('created at'), auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(_('modified at'), auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'experience'
        verbose_name = _('experience')
        verbose_name_plural = _('experiences')
        ordering = ('-start_date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return getattr(self, 'title', '')

    @property
    def experience(self):
        if self.end_date:
            return (self.end_date - self.start_date).days
        else:
            return (datetime.datetime.now().date() - self.start_date).days

    def get_formated_experience(self):
        days = self.experience
        total_months = round(days/30)
        years = int(total_months/12)
        months = round(((total_months/12)%1)*12)
        year_txt = 'years' if years > 1 else 'year'
        month_txt = 'months' if months > 1 else 'month'
        return "%s %s %s %s" %(years, year_txt, months, month_txt)
```

**Location Model**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    """
    """
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    display_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10, null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = LocationManager()
```

Comment: Kindly show your serializer code.

Comment: i have edited my question with my script so please look a glance :)

Comment: You could set `blank=True` in your models.

Comment: Thanks Fazil Zaid,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting Two types of validation error according to snapshot.

1. Field  is required
2. Expected a dictionary and got a string

The required field error occurs when you have set field as required in your model. You can change this by adding `blank=True` in your model for that field.
For second error, your serializer is expecting a dictionary and you are sending a string. You can remove this validation by writing your custom create method.

```
class ExperienceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    user_location = LocationField()
    location = LocationField()

    class Meta:
        model = Experience
        fields = ('id', 'company_name', 'company', 'description', 'location',
                'title', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'is_current', 'user_location')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # you create code for that models.
```

Your seriailzers will be like this

```
class ProfessionalRegistrationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=20, write_only=True)
    experiences = ExperienceSerializer(required=False)
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password',
        'experiences', 'headline')

    def validate_email(self, value):
        from validate_email_address import validate_email
        if User.all_objects.filter(email=value.lower()).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User with this email already exists.')
        # if not validate_email(value.lower(), check_mx=True):
        #     raise serializers.ValidationError('It looks like you may have entered an incorrect email address.')
        return value.lower()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        experiences = validated_data.get('experiences')
        password = validated_data.get('password')
        email = validated_data.get('email')
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=email.lower(),
            email=email.lower(),
            role_id=1)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        user_location = experiences.get('user_location')
        location_object = None
        if user_location:
            location_object, created = Location.objects.get_or_create(display_name=user_location.get('display_name'), latitude= user_location.get('latitude'), longitude=user_location.get('longitude'))
        user_experience = Experience.objects.create(user=user, company_name=experiences.get('company_name'), location=location_object)
        return user
```

---

```
class ExperienceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    user_location = LocationField()
    location = LocationField()

    class Meta:
        model = Experience
        fields = ('id', 'company_name', 'company', 'description', 'location',
                'title', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'is_current', 'user_location')
```

Comment: Please look 

class ProfessionalRegistrationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

here already defined 

def create(self, validated_data):

please point out where should be change to remove validation for "Expected a dictionary and got a string" I'm new in django plz help me :)

Comment: The serializer you are mentioning is for User model. So create function will be for User objects. The fields for which you want to remove validation is of Experience model so create function will be for serializer of Experience.

Comment: Would you like to explain about "validated_data" how it works?

Comment: `validated_data` is a dictionary which contains all valid data for that serializer. You do not need to pass it to serializer. That create function will be automatically called when you call `serializerr.save()`

Comment: Thanks for your response M Hassan. why place ** like **validated_data ?
eg: return YourModel.objects.create(user=self.context.get('user'), **validated_data)

Comment: When you provide dictionary in like `Model.objects.create(**data)`, Here data should be like `data={'field_a': 'value', 'field_b': 'value'}`. It is another way of doing `Model.objects.create(field_a='value', field_b='value')`. In your case, you do not need to pass validated data to `YourMode.objects.create` function. That create function and create function of serializer are different things.

Comment: just edit my code please see and reply me :(, i m confused !

Comment: Yes         def create(self, validated_data):

            return Experience.objects.create(location='', start_date='')  please look this and suggest how to write function to remove validation from location and date fileds

Comment: Kindly share your Models (User, Experience and Location)

Comment: Just Edit my Question and added Experience and Location Model

Comment: Are you using User from Django auth or custom user model?